# I am getting JsEngineLoadException when using bundle transformer in asp.net application view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, less, bundletransformer

i am facing below exception when i am trying to use bundle transformer to transform .less file, this issue seems to occur intermittently and not always.

As i can see there is some Win32 Exception in JavascriptEngineSwitcher, can some one help with actual cause of this issue.
Below is the stacktrace:

System Configuration being Used:
OS: Windows Server 2008R2
IE: IE8 (Internet Explorer Version 8)

```
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.Utilities.Utils.CreateInstanceByFullTypeName[T](String fullTypeName)
at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineSwitcher.CreateJsEngineInstance(String name)
at BundleTransformer.Less.Compilers.LessCompiler..ctor(Func`1 createJsEngineInstance, CompilationOptions defaultOptions)
at BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1 assets)
at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1 assets, Boolean isDebugMode)
at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.CssTransformer.Transform(IList`1 assets, BundleResponse bundleResponse, VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean isDebugMode)
at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response, Boolean isDebugMode)
at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs)
at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
at ASP._Page_XXXXXXX_YYYYYY_ZZZZZ__Head_cshtml.Execute() in c:\*******\*******\*******\*******\*******\*******\*******\_Head.cshtml:line 13
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at AW.Web.Mvc.BaseView`1.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
at ASP.xxxxx_yyyyy_zzzzz_aaaaa_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineLoadException: During loading of MSIE JavaScript engine error has occurred.   
See more details:

The requested lookup key was was not found in any active activation context.
at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine..ctor(MsieConfiguration msieConfig)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested lookup key was was not found in any active activation context.
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptJsEngineBase..ctor(String clsid, String engineModeName, String lowerIeVersion, Boolean useEcmaScript5Polyfill, Boolean useJson2Library)
at MsieJavaScriptEngine.MsieJsEngine..ctor(JsEngineMode engineMode, Boolean useEcmaScript5Polyfill, Boolean useJson2Library)
at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine..ctor(MsieConfiguration msieConfig)
```

Answer (score 3):

For correct working of the MSIE JavaScript Engine it is recommended to install Internet Explorer 9 and above on a server.

You have 2 variants to solve this problem:

1. Install Internet Explorer 9 or above on server.
2. Use a JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 package (requires the Visual C++ 
   Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio) instead of the 
   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie package.

BundleTransformer.Less will not work without a Internet Explorer 9 or above (an “Out of stack space” error will occur).
This error will occur when executing a large amount of JS code, i.e. most part of the Bundle Transformer modules will cause this error.